# Combine two regular expressions for php

Tags: php, regex

I have these two regular expression

```
^(((98)|(\+98)|(0098)|0)(9){1}[0-9]{9})+$
^(9){1}[0-9]{9}+$
```

How can I combine these phrases together?

valid phone :

```
just start with : 0098 , +98 , 98 , 09 and 9
sample :
00989151855454
+989151855454
989151855454
09151855454
9151855454
```

Comment: @Jan ok, i'm edited question

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex

```
^(?:98|\+98|0098|0)?9[0-9]{9}$
```

matches

```
00989151855454
+989151855454
989151855454
09151855454
9151855454
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/VFc4pK/1/

However note that you are requiring to have a `9` as first digit after the country code or `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't provided what passes and what doesn't, but I think this will work if I understand correctly...

```
/^\+?0{0,2}98?/
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/VpE2Ff/1)

```
^         Matches the start of the string
\+?       Matches 0 or 1 plus symbols (the backslash is to escape)
0{0,2}    Matches between 0 and 2 (0, 1, and 2) of the 0 character
9         Matches a literal 9
8?        Matches 0 or 1 of the literal 8 characters
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your second regex, it looks like you want to make the first part `((98)|(\+98)|(0098)|0)` in your first regex optional. Just make it optional by putting `?` after it and it will allow the numbers allowed by second regex. Change this,

```
^(((98)|(\+98)|(0098)|0)(9){1}[0-9]{9})+$
```

to,

```
^(?:98|\+98|0098|0)?9[0-9]{9}$
                   ^ this makes the non-grouping pattern optional which contains various alternations you want to allow.
```

I've made few more corrections in the regex. Use of `{1}` is redundant as that's the default behavior of a character, with or without it. and you don't need to unnecessarily group regex unless you need the groups. And I've removed the outer most parenthesis and `+` after it as that is not needed.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q3vJgY/1)**

Comment: Basically same answer as me! +1